# How can i execute a javascript function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a javascript code that setup a websocket connection and have several functions.
The websocket works fine.
but i want to run a javascript function from the script inside the html code.this does not work. if i run the function from a onclick event, then it works fine (see the button).

i have tried the body onload but it does not work.

My goal is: execute the function OnloadFunction if the webpage is loaded. Then it should send a string with websocket.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">
<title>Testpage</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; background-color:#5593F1}
.button { background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 10px 40px;
text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}
.button2 {background-color: #77878A;}
</style>
<script>
var connection;
connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/'); 
connection.onopen = function () {  connection.send('Connect ' + new Date()); }; 
connection.onerror = function (error) {    console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);};
connection.onmessage = function (e) {  console.log('Server: ', e.data);};

function OnloadFunction() {
  connection.send('* Test22');  
  alert("Hello! ");     
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="javascript:OnloadFunction();"> 
<h1>Testpage</h1>
<p>Suche....</p>
<p><a href="/read.html"><button class="button" onclick="OnloadFunction()">read</button></a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple test from me but does not work also

```
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Suche...</p>
<p><a href="/read.html"><button class="button"   onclick="OnloadFunction()">Lesen</button></a></p>
<script>
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/'); 
connection.onopen = function () {  connection.send('Connect ' + new Date()); }; 
connection.onerror = function (error) {    console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);};
connection.onmessage = function (e) {  console.log('Server: ', e.data);};
connection.send('* Test22');
</script>  
</body>
```

What is wrong? How can i execute the function OnloadFunction() in the html code if the webside is loaded?

**EDIT1:**
Thank you for all the suggestions. i have tried much different ways but nothing works.

Now I am close to a solution but I do not understand the new error.
The function start() is executet because of window.onload=start;
But the code after connection.onmessage = function(evt) { console.log(evt);};
is only executet if the alert("TEST___"); is in the code. if i delete this line then the code after that is not executet. Why is the code not executet without alert("TEST___"); ?? With the button onclick all works well without the alert.

Here my code websock2.js (the alters are only for testing):

```
var connection;
function OnloadFunction() {
  connection.send('* Test22'+' x'); 
  alert("LOADED! ");      
}

function start() {
  alert("Start! "); 
  connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/'); 
  <!-- connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.5:81/',['arduino']); -->
  connection.onopen = function () {  connection.send('Connect ' + new Date()); }; 
  connection.onerror = function (error) {    console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);};
  connection.onmessage = function(evt) { console.log(evt);};
  alert("TEST___");       
  connection.send('* Test22'+' x'); 
  console.log('effekt: '); 
  alert("LOADED! ");      
}

window.onload=start;
```

Here my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
  <link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">
  <title>Testpage</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <script src="websock2.js" async></script> 
  <style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; background-color:#5593F1}
    .button { background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 10px 40px;
    text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}
    .button2 {background-color: #77878A;}
  </style>


</head>
<body>
  <h1>Testpage</h1>
  <p>read....</p>
  <p><a href="/read.html"><button class="button" onclick="OnloadFunction()">Lesen</button></a></p>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you want to execute the code just after the page is complete loaded or you want to execute when the page is loading?

Comment: don't add listeners to your html. For the page loaded do (in your js) `window.onload = OnLoadFunction`

Comment: use window.onload ()

Comment: Wild speculation: You're trying to send the message before the connection is opened and you should do it `connection.onopen` instead of `window.onload`.

Comment: @MonicaAcha — While that is better *style* … since the load event isn't working … doing the same thing in a better style seems like a poor idea.

Comment: I have tried many but nothing works. i have updated my Post.
Please look at Edit1